# Encryption / Decryption sqlite database using java

Tags: java, sqlite, encryption, jdbc

Is there any free library / Java API to encrypt and decrypt sqlite database in java ? I am using SQLite JDBC driver as part of xerial project.

Thanks,
Deep

Comment: Do you want to decrypt / encrypt the database while it's closed? That's relatively easy - but then you should change the title of the question to 'how to decrypt / encrypt a file'... If not, then there are various SQLite encryption extensions. But I don't know a Java library.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So do you mean, I can simply encrypt it as a normal file and then decrypt it like a normal file before reading the records from the tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an encryption library ([sqlite-crypt](http://sqlite-crypt.com/)) available in C, but if you want to do it in Java, I would simply encrypt the file like any other file. See this example of [file encryption/decryption in Java](http://cs.saddleback.edu/rwatkins/CS4B/Crypto/FileEncryptor.html).

Comment: Just a question, won't encrypting and decrypting the file like that leave the file vulnerable? i mean jdbc picks up the file, which means you will have to decrypt the file to let's say the temp folder, and then use that fine in stead of the encrypted one. Won't this leave a small window of attack? I'd like my data to go from my encrypted database straight to my memory.